# Do UK graduate employers take into account which university you got your degree from, or just the grade you achieved?

Tags: career-development, education

The question excludes the top 10 UK universities.

I am currently an undergraduate studying Software Engineering at Westminster University (ranked 90/120 in the UK) and have been offered the chance to transfer to Goldsmiths University - University of London (Ranked 40/120).

I was wondering if it would be likely to advance my career if I took the place. Do employers typically judge degrees from different universities differently?

Comment: Always go to the best place you can get into.

Answer (score 4):

I interview and hire developers.  This is my experience of looking at (recent) graduates.

A good school is a useful indicator of how rigorous your education is - but it is *only* an indicator.  I've spoken to people from top flight universities who couldn't explain how HTTP requests work!

A much better indicator of competence - in my opinion - is your portfolio.  What open source projects have you contributed to?  Which conferences have you presented at?  What hackdays have you attended? Have you won any prizes?  Do you have a start-up you run on the side?

That said, some employers *will* only take people from specific universities.  The higher ranked, the better.  Additionally, the quality of teaching is likely to be significantly better at Goldsmiths.

My advice is not to concern yourself so much with the absolute rank - but what you can achieve at each institution.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

When I started my current job my boss told me that he nearly didn't interview me because he'd recently interviewed someone from my course who lacked basic programming skills. This story is anecdote so I don't pretend to back it up as an across the board fact, however it does demonstrate that if a recruiter has a bad impression of your course/institution it might count against you. My advice would be to not look at the overall university rank but A) the content of the course and B) any information you can find about students impressions of the course. A good university is still capable of running a lousy course and a lower ranked university might have strengths in some areas that defy its reputation.

Good luck with your applications.